# Inserting date as Date object in a database using Java 8?

Tags: java, sql, date, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm working on a project that would require calculations on dates. I'm looking for a way to store date as a **Date** object inside a access database but every method gives an error. I'm using UcanAccess drivers with Java 8.

My stripped Code:

```
//========================== SetupDB =====================================//
public void setupDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        c1 = DriverManager.getConnection(ABDebatePro.DBURL);
        stmt = c1.createStatement();
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
}
//========================== InsertDB ====================================//
public void insertDB(int m, String ft, String st, int s1, int s2, Date d) {
    MatchNumber = m;
    FirstTeam = ft;
    SecondTeam = st;
    FirstTeamScore = s1;
    SecondTeamScore = s2;
    MatchDate = d;
    setupDB();
    try {
        String sql = "insert into Schedule (MatchNumber, FirstTeam, SecondTeam, FirstTeamScore, SecondTeamScore, MatchDate)  values " + "(" + m + ",'" + ft + "','" + st + "'," + s1 + "," + s2+ ",'" + d  + "')";
        int z = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        c1.close(); 
    } catch (Exception fe) {
        System.out.println(fe);
    }
}
 //========================== Main ========================================//
public static void main(String[] args) {
Schedule sch = new Schedule();
try {
     java.sql.Date date1 = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-10-25");
     sch.insertDB(3, "Turtles", "Aligators", 4, 3, date1);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

My Log:

```
insert into Schedule (MatchNumber, FirstTeam, SecondTeam, FirstTeamScore, SecondTeamScore, MatchDate)  values (3,'Turtles','Aligators',4,3,'2016-10-25')
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

My database:

[image: Database snapshot]

Comment: `java.sql.Date` drops the hours, minutes, seconds. In the database there is not a DATE but DATETIME. Java Timestamp? Or you could use the nicer java 8 classes LocalDate, LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using *dynamic SQL* to construct the SQL statement in `insertDB`, and that statement contains an invalid date literal. You should be using a `PreparedStatement` and a *parameterized query* like so:

```java
String sql =
        "INSERT INTO Schedule " +
        "(MatchNumber, FirstTeam, SecondTeam, FirstTeamScore, SecondTeamScore, MatchDate) " +
        "VALUES " +
        "(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
PreparedStatement ps = c1.prepareStatement(sql)
ps.setInt(1, m);
ps.setString(2, ft);
ps.setString(3, st);
ps.setInt(4, s1);
ps.setInt(5, s2);
ps.setDate(6, d);
int z = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I just did this and looked up my question and you answered. Great job! This works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

An example method for you:

```
public void getSqlDate() { 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = 2016; 
    int month = 9;   //month is zero-based
    int day = 25
    cal.set(year, month, date);
    return new Date(cal.getTime());
}
```

Note that the constructor for the java.sql.Date really wants a long value that represents the # "milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"

See JavaDocs for [java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: Sorry, but this does not address the issue, and `java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-10-25")` is a perfectly acceptable way of creating a `java.sql.Date` value.